# Insert categories and sub categories from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have 2 tables - **Import** and **Template** and the Template table has 3 levels of categories. I need to insert categories from Import to Template however Import only has one column.

[sql tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9roC.png)

From pic, it should only insert 5 categories because there are 5 distinct ones. There are 2 sub1 category and 1 sub2 category. CSD_ID in the Template table is auto generated. The insert statement should update the Primary_Cat_Id with its parent CSD_ID.

Example, Toilet is a sub2 of Domestic so it should get the CSD_ID of Domestic and populate in the Primary_Cat_Id but it is also a sub1 of Bath so it should get the CSD_ID of Bath and fill it in Parent_ID.

Last_Lev is either 1 or 0. 1 means it is the last level and 0 means there are sub category below it

Comment: Sorry, Parent_ID for Bath should be 1

Comment: so the template table is empty now and you want to fill it with certain values? if so, you'd probably need to do an after insert trigger to grab the CSD_ID/Category of the insert and check it against the import table, then update parent_id, primary_cat_id, last_lev accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could do this is by creating an `AFTER INSERT` trigger on the Template table, such that when you insert from the Import table, it'll update the values for `Parent_Id`, `Lev_No`, `Primary_Cat_Id` and `Last_Lev` automatically.

I'm assuming your table structures look something like this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Import', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE Import;

CREATE TABLE Import (
      [Main Category] VARCHAR(255) -- NOT NULL?
    , [Sub Category 1] VARCHAR(255)
    , [Sub Category 2] VARCHAR(255));

INSERT Import 
VALUES ('Domestic', NULL, NULL)
     , ('Domestic', 'House', NULL)
     , ('Domestic', NULL, NULL)
     , ('Domestic', NULL, NULL)
     , ('Domestic', 'Bath', 'Toilet')
     , ('Domestic', NULL, NULL)
     , ('Commercial', NULL, NULL)
     , ('Commercial', NULL, NULL)
     , ('Commercial', NULL, NULL)
     , ('Commercial', NULL, NULL)
     , ('Commercial', NULL, NULL)
     , ('Commercial', NULL, NULL);

IF OBJECT_ID('Template', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE Template;

CREATE TABLE Template (
      CSD_ID INT IDENTITY (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY
    , Category VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
    , Parent_Id INT
    , Lev_No INT
    , Primary_Cat_Id INT
    , Last_Lev BIT);
```

Your trigger should look something like the following:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tr_Template_Insert', 'TR') IS NOT NULL DROP TRIGGER tr_Template_Insert;
GO

CREATE TRIGGER tr_Template_Insert
ON Template
AFTER INSERT
AS BEGIN
    WITH CTE AS (
        SELECT RN, cats, lvl
        FROM (
            SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RN 
            FROM Import) T
        CROSS APPLY (
            VALUES ([Main Category], 1)
                 , ([Sub Category 1], 2)
                 , ([Sub Category 2], 3)) S(cats,lvl)
        WHERE S.cats IS NOT NULL
        )
    UPDATE T
    SET Last_Lev = Z.lastLev
        , Primary_Cat_Id = COALESCE(Z.PrimaryCat, T.CSD_ID)
        , Parent_Id = COALESCE(Z.ParentCat, T.CSD_ID)
        , Lev_No = Z.levNo
    FROM Template T
    JOIN (
        SELECT C.cats
             , MAX(CASE WHEN C.lvl = LL.lastlev THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) lastLev
             , MAX(Pri.primarycat) PrimaryCat
             , MAX(Par.parentcat) ParentCat
             , MAX(lvl) levNo
        FROM CTE C
        JOIN inserted I ON I.Category = C.cats
        OUTER APPLY (
            SELECT T.CSD_ID
            FROM CTE CZ
            JOIN Template T ON T.Category = CZ.cats
            WHERE CZ.RN = C.RN
            AND CZ.lvl = 1) Pri(primarycat)
        OUTER APPLY (
            SELECT T.CSD_ID
            FROM CTE CZ
            JOIN Template T ON T.Category = CZ.cats
            WHERE CZ.RN = C.RN
            AND CZ.lvl = C.lvl-1) Par(parentcat)
        OUTER APPLY (
            SELECT MAX(lvl)
            FROM CTE CZ
            WHERE CZ.RN = C.RN) LL(lastlev)
        GROUP BY C.cats) Z ON Z.cats = T.Category;
END
```

There might be an easier way to do this, but this technically works (at least with the sample data).

After that, you'd just need a cursor or something to do the inserts one by one, starting with the main categories:

```
DECLARE @cats VARCHAR(255);

DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR
    SELECT cats
    FROM (
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RN 
        FROM Import) Z
    CROSS APPLY (
        VALUES ([Main Category], 1)
             , ([Sub Category 1], 2)
             , ([Sub Category 2], 3)) S(cats,lvl)
    LEFT JOIN Template T ON T.Category = S.cats
    WHERE S.cats IS NOT NULL
    AND T.Category IS NULL
    GROUP BY cats
    ORDER BY MIN(lvl); -- main cats first, then subcat1, then subcat2

OPEN curs;
FETCH NEXT FROM curs INTO @cats;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    INSERT Template(Category)
    VALUES (@cats);
    FETCH NEXT FROM curs INTO @cats;
END
CLOSE curs;
DEALLOCATE curs;
```

The cursor will insert main category, then sub category 1, then subcategory 2 and the trigger will fill in the rest of the values.

Comment: Thank you. Would it be easier if I use a Merge function? I was advised to look at a Merge to do insert and after insert.

Comment: @Jay you could certainly do it manually (or, say, do one column at a time, starting with main categories, then moving onto subcategory 1 then subcategory 2). I guess that would require three sets of inserts. The basic logic would be similar, though. You'd need to compare the tables and find the parent cat, primary cat id, whether it's a last level.